# Creating a dictionary with nested arrays

Tags: python

How do you take a pre-existing dictionary and essentially add an item from a list into the dictionary as a tuple using a for loop?  I made this example below.  I want to take `color_dict` and reformat it so that each item would be in the format `'R':['red',1]`.

I got as far as below, but then couldn't figure out how to do the last part.

```
lista = {'red':'R', 'orange':'O', 'yellow':'Y', 'green':'G',
        'blue':'B', 'indigo':'I', 'violet':'V'}
color_dict = {'R':1, 'O':2, 'Y':3, 'G':4, 'B':5, 'I':6, 'V':7}

a = color_dict.keys()
color_keys = []
color_vals = []

for x in lista[0::2]:
    color_keys.append(x)
for x in lista[1::2]:
    color_vals.append(x)

new = zip(color_keys, color_vals)
new_dict = dict(new)
print new_dict
```

If anyone has any other suggestions that would be great, I'm not understanding how to use dict comprehension.

Comment: Do you get errors while running the code? I get `KeyError`s in the `for` loop with `lista` but using `a` in its place produces some output.

Comment: Up to the point I have written, I don't get any errors.  But, I can't figure out how to go about adding items from one dictionary to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do is to loop through the items in `lista` and for each pair `color: colkey` find the respective value in `color_dict` (indexed by `colkey`). And then you just need to stitch everything together: `colkey: [color, color_dict[colkey]]` is the new item in the new dict for each item in the `lista` dict.

You can use a dict comprehension to build this:

```
>>> new_dict = {colkey: [color, color_dict[colkey]] for color, colkey in lista.items()}
>>> new_dict
{'O': ['orange', 2], 'Y': ['yellow', 3], 'V': ['violet', 7], 'R': ['red', 1], 'G': ['green', 4], 'B': ['blue', 5], 'I': ['indigo', 6]}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following how I do that.

Comment: This is a great answer, very simple. I highly recommend working through it until you know why it works, you'll learn a lot about python!

Comment: I'm not understanding what is my colkey item.  Could you explain to me what that refers to?

Comment: @bk4488 We’re looping through all key-value pairs of `lista`; and for each pair, `color` is the dictionary key and `colkey` its value. That’s what happens in the `for color, colkey in lista.items()` part. And then, we construct a new dictionary using dict comprehension where each item of the *new dictionary* has the key `colkey` and the value `[color, color_dict[colkey]]`.